# Overflow hidden text gets cut off

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass

So I am working this animation where text slide up from the bottom of the line. A simplified version of the code can be previewed here:

https://codepen.io/Deka87/pen/jGzVvY

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span>Harley</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;

    > span {
        display: block;
        font-size: 5rem;
        font-weight: bold;
        line-height: 1;
        transform: translateY(100%);
        transition: all .3s;

        &.active {
            transform: translateY(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works OK, except that a few bottom pixels of the text get cut off. I do understand this happens because of the reduced line height (so please don't mark it as a duplicate of other similar questions), however I do need to keep the line height.

Is there a way to create this kind of animation avoiding text being cut off and keeping the reduced line height?

Comment: Smaller font-size could work, or padding.

Comment: @Mouser, I should stick to the design, so smalller font-size is not an option. Padding will also increase space between lines, which is a contrary of what I try to achieve reducing line height.

Comment: @sdvnksv Can you please share the other lines which will also come inside the show/hide span, so that the question is more clear!

Comment: `margin-top:-5px;margin-bottom:5px;` on the span element works fine

Comment: @NarenMurali, the text can be any. This is a template an end user will fill with content. I've added a couple of lines for you to play with.

Comment: @sdvnksv I tried with padding it looks fine! can you please verify my answer!

Comment: @pokeybit, yes, that would work. However I'll need to wrap it inside something else and add it some top padding to put things back in the original position. That's what I tried to avoid, however, this seems like the only solution.

Comment: Well `box-sizing: Border-box` on the div and a larger padding, like 10px, gives a clean result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can offset the font by using relative positioning for the `span` and adjusting the CSS property `top:-9px` to achieve the required offset.

Idea obtained from the below answer.

<kbd>**SO Answer**</kbd>

**CSS:**

```
div {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;

    > span {
        display: block;
        font-size: 5rem;
        top: -9px;
        position: relative;
        font-weight: bold;
        line-height: 1;
        transform: translateY(100%);
        transition: all .3s;

        &.active {
            transform: translateY(0);
        }
    }
}
```

<kbd>**Codepen Demo**</kbd>

Comment: With this approach, you make the reduced line height useless because you increase the space between lines with additional padding.

Comment: @sdvnksv I tried a different approach. please check!